# Temporally Dither an Image (Image to PWM Image)

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output, image-processing

## Background

I want to display *rich, vibrant images* on my theoretical fancy custom display, but due to budget constraints, it displays everything in 3-bit colour! Whilst [Regular Dithering](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/26554/dither-a-grayscale-image) would work, I don't want to sacrifice resolution, so I would like my images to be dithered through time!

## Specs

Provided an Input Image, I would like you to show me several 3-bit color versions of that image, such that the average colour of all images is the original image.

### I/O

You must take an image as input.

You may either animate the image (Return a GIF, Video, or on the screen), or take time as an additional input. If time is taken as input, the output must be Deterministic for a given image and time, and must return as a static image.

### Example

[image: Girl with Pearl Earing]

*From [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Johannes_Vermeer_(1632-1675)_-_The_Girl_With_The_Pearl_Earring_(1665).jpg)*

> [image: Looks kind of like TV static] [image: Static]

*A lot of quality was lost between recording the output and converting it to a gif, thus a still has also been provided*

### Victory

The victory condition is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), as per previously stated budget constraints.

## Final Notes

Please consider the risk of photo-sensitivity when uploading an answer, and keep images to either external links, or wrapped in a spoiler. Videos of your solution running are not required, but are welcome.

Comment: What is the color depth of input image I need to support?

Comment: What does 3-bit color means? How should I calculate average color? Will input image always use RGB color space?

Comment: @tsh Support needs to only be provided for a 24bit color image (8 bytes per channel, 3 channel). 3-bit color refers to an image in which each channel, red green and blue, may only be ON or OFF,  (Eg. 0, or 255). Average Colour should be calculated such that any sample of images, when sufficiently large, should have each channel of each pixel average out to the input image. Input Image may be assumed to be in any format convenient. Has this helped?

Comment: I think these would be helpful. Would you mind to edit these into the question itself?

Comment: In your specs, you write "Provided an Input Image, I would like you to show me several 3-bit color versions of that image".  But in the result (spoiler) part of your example, I don't see the several different 3-bit color versions of the input, I only see the combined result.  What am I missing?

Comment: @theorist As stated in I/O, the output must either be animated, such as the first option in the spoiler, or a static output for a given time input. Both the example images provided are 3-bit (Ignoring the aliasing artifacts in the GIF)

Comment: You should have further constraints on what counts as dithering, as otherwise something like `f=lambda i,t:[int(p>t%255)for p in i]` is a valid submission

Comment: @AnttiP I did consider that as a solution, and whilst it's not the most visually interesting answer, it's not that much more complex than `p>rand()`, and enforcing interesting solutions is difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 24 bytes

```
Sign[#-Mod[1##,1]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7v@T9pIWeuYnpqQ5BibkFDsGZ6XnRyrq@@SnRJco6hrGxag5aYGmXxJLE//8B)

Input `[image,time]`, where `image` is a 3-channel RGB `Image`, and outputs a frame.

A fairly straightforward approach: output whenever the floor of the accumulated value increases. Mathematica's `Image`s support arithmetic and can contain values of any size, but are clamped between 0 and 1 when displayed.

For the image in OP, a GIF output of t=1,2,...,255 can be viewed [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yg92Ehh1AhFyzlYAS8ZcoYqWpQ1IF1WA/view) (caution: blocks of flashing colors).
Averaging the frames: 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) -ap, 110 bytes

```perl
srand($F[3]=1);
$_=(map{splice@b,rand@b,1}@b=((1)x($o=int$_*8/256),(0)x(8-$o)))[$ENV{F}]for@F[4..$#F];
$_="@F\n"
```

[Can't try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@4KDEvRUPFLdo41tZQ01ol3lYjN7GgurggJzM51SFJByQNpAxrHZJsNTQMNSs0VPJtM/NKVOK1LPSNTM00dTQMgIIWuir5mpqa0SqufmHVbrWxaflFDm7RJnp6KspusSBTlRzcYvKU/v//l19QkpmfV/xfN7EAAA)

...but instead you can create an 8 frames animated GIF image with:

```perl
echo 'srand(7);$F[3]=1;$_=(map{splice@b,rand@b,1}@b=((1)x($o=int$_*8/256),(0)x(8-$o)))[$ENV{F}]for@F[4..$#F];$_="@F\n"' > program.pl
wget -N -O img.jpg "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/66/Johannes_Vermeer_%281632-1675%29_-_The_Girl_With_The_Pearl_Earring_%281665%29.jpg/335px-Johannes_Vermeer_%281632-1675%29_-_The_Girl_With_The_Pearl_Earring_%281665%29.jpg"
convert -compress none img.jpg img.ppm
perl -i -pe's/\n/ /' img.ppm 
for f in {0..7};do cat img.ppm|F=$f perl -ap program.pl > img-frame$f.ppm;done  #~10sec
convert -delay 1 -loop 0 img-frame*.ppm img-animated.gif
xdg-open img-animated.gif
```

The `program.pl` reads the one line input (the example image of this challenge converted to the Plain PPM format) from STDIN and the frame number 0-7 (the time) from the environment variable F. The above commands works with `bash` shell, `wget`, the `convert` program from ImageMagick and `xdg-open` or any image viewer capable of viewing animated GIF images. To change to 16 frames, replace 7 with 15 and the two 8's with 16. Animated GIF image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s5WDGjwKLowdmildkYxUWGOWpRjS-Av6/view?usp=sharing