# Program an Artistically Rich Comic Strip

Tags: popularity-contest, ascii-art, graphical-output

#### The Challenge

**Program a comic strip.** As artistically rich and detailed as you can possibly make it, so long as it complies with the following rules:

- the comic must be your own original work, *not* a duplicate or approximation of an existing comic (you may however use characters from an existing strip as an homage, if you desire)
- the comic must contain at least one panel, and all panels must be surrounded by a clear border
- the comic must contain at least one blurb of readable text with ≥ 10 characters that is clearly recognizable as text; this may come in the form of a caption, a text bubble, a thought bubble, a sign, etc.
- the comic may be graphic-based or text-based (more on this below)

  - if text-based, the comic must have dimensions of at least 30x25 chars, and no greater than 160x80 chars
  - if graphic-based, the comic must have dimensions of at least 300x300 pixels, but no greater than 1600x1000 pixels
- the comic must be generated by a program whose **core code** contains at most **512 bytes**
- the comic must comply with the StackExchange [content policy](http://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy)

#### What is "Core Code"?

This is a somewhat novel concept, hence please bear with me in patience.

For programming language *X*, consider the most elementary code that outputs a single (black) circle or ASCII letter `o` at coordinates (10,10) on a (white) canvas and then terminates. The colours *black* and *white* above may refer to any two colours. "Output" refers to text being printed to **stdout**/console, text being outputted to a file, a graphic being drawn to a window, or a graphic being saved to a file. The two key points are that

- the code is able to render this most basic output
- the code contains nothing nonessential (within reason, and subject to reader scrutiny) for rendering this specific output, which includes comments (whitespace is fine)

This elementary program is called your **shell**. From the shell, delete as many or as few commands as you wish and identify at most two *insertion points* where new code can/will go. Any code inserted at these points is called your **core code**. The length of your core code is the total length (in bytes) of code inserted at these points.

The following are six representative examples of acceptable shells:

```
--- Text Output with C (type 1) ---

#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

void P( int x, int y, char c ) {
    COORD p = { x, y };

    SetConsoleCursorPosition( GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE ), p );
    printf( "%c", c );
}

int main() {
    system( "cls" );
    P( 10, 10, 'o' );
    return 0;
}



--- Text Output with C (type 2) ---

int main() {
    puts( "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n         o" );
    return 0;
}



--- Graphical Output with Javascript ---

(function(){
    document.body.innerHTML = '<canvas id="cvs1" width="300" height="300"></canvas>';

    with( document.getElementById('cvs1').getContext('2d') ) {
        fillStyle = 'rgb(192,192,192)';
        strokeStyle = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
        fillRect( 0, 0, 300, 300 );
        beginPath();
        arc( 10, 10, 5, 0, 2*Math.PI );
        stroke();
    }
})();



--- Text Output with HTML ---

<html><body bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;o
</body></html>



--- Graphical Output with Python (Turtle Library) ---

from turtle import*

fd( 10 );
rt( 90 );
fd( 10 );
circle( 5, 360 );



--- Text Output with MATLAB ---

G = repmat( ' ', 30, 30 );
G(10,10) = 'o';
disp( G );
```

If you prefer, your shell may be empty.

I have started a discussion [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18274/room-for-discussing-shells-as-pertaining-to-core-code) for readers unsure of what the community considers appropriate in this respect. Note that this is a **popularity contest**, so making sure the community doesn't consider you to be breaking the rules is important.

#### What To Present

1. your **core code**, either as a single block or as two separate blocks if you have two separate insertion points
2. your **shell**, using the distinctive ✰ character (Unicode U+2730) to mark any insertion points (or simply say "no shell")
3. your comic in a text block, or as an image, or as a link to either of the aforementioned. If your comic is text-based and looks better in a different font, charset, etc., you can provide a screenshot or a link to an online environment where the text can be viewed.

#### Scoring

This is a **popularity contest** and hence your score is at the whim of the voters.

This is a competition about artistically rich comic book (or graphic novel) style artwork. Humour is a nice touch, but should not be used as a principle criterion for judging entries.

Voters can of course vote any way they want, but as a rough set of guidelines they (you) might wish to consider:

- artistry (whether the comic is especially artful within the artist's chosen medium), with emphasis on features such as

  - beautiful art
  - texturing
  - detailed and/or recognizable characters
  - rich embellishments such as call-outs, fancy borders, shading effects, etc.
- complexity (whether the artist/programmer really gets his/her money's worth out of 512 characters)
- creativity (special additional "wow" factors that make the comic stand out in some way)

Feel free to raise questions or concerns in the comments section.

Comment: What's with the [code-golf] tag?

Comment: @Quincunx: Your core code is limited to 512 bytes. That's an incredibly tight restriction. [code-golf] seemed appropriate. Maybe [restricted-source]?

Comment: This seems to be a contest about art and writing, and not about programming. I understand there's a strict character requirement that forces efficient code, but that's likely to be a question of limiting the number and type of shape used in the comic, making it an "art golf". [Previous meta discussion about art](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1947/the-line-between-art-and-programming). I'm leaning towards close voting, but will discuss in chat.

Comment: @xnor: No artist who isn't also an incredibly competent programmer could undertake this challenge. And besides that, we have dozens if not hundreds of art-based challenges on PPCG.

Comment: `code-golf` is for challenges where you solve a problem with the fewest bytes. `restricted-source` is for restricting what characters you are allowed to use in your program. I don't think this falls into either of those. http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/35569/tweetable-mathematical-art imposes a similar restriction and doesn't have a tag for that part.

Comment: @chilemagic: I've dropped the tag. If readers can think of one that applies to "artificially restricted source length", please feel free to add this tag.

Comment: Readers may be interested in a lengthy discussion between @xnor and myself in the "Nineteenth Byte" chatroom. I'm out for the night, but additional input is of course welcome.

Comment: [Link to start of chat discussion.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18392937#18392937)

Comment: The size requirements need rewording. Is 500 x 200 pixels smaller or greater than 300 x 300 pixels?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because its focus is on art, not programming

Comment: To any interested parties, I've voiced some frustrations in the [art meta discussion](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2431/31019).

Answer (score 8):

## HTML (with JS)

### Shell

```
<canvas id='cnv' width=410 height=300></canvas>
<script>
var c = document.getElementById('cnv');
with (C = c.getContext('2d')) {
✰
    beginPath();
    arc(10, 10, 5, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    stroke();
}
</script>
```

### Full code (511 characters of core code)

It's a runnable Stack Snippet! You can try it yourself, right here, from your own browser. (Note: text may overflow if you have a different font than me.)

```html
<canvas id='cnv' width=410 height=300></canvas>
<script>
var c = document.getElementById('cnv');
with (C = c.getContext('2d')) {
font='9px serif'
r=(m=Math).random;p=m.PI
function f(x,y,t,l,T){for(i=0;i<(l||100);++i)C.fillRect(x+r(),y+r(),3,3),x+=m.sin(t),y+=m.cos(t),t+=(T||0)}
for(n=0;n<5;++n){f((N=100*n),n,0)
f(N+10,y=20,0,0,0.1)
f(N+y,30,0,30)
for(v=40;v<70;v+=20)f(N+y,v,0.3,30),f(N+y,v,-0.3,30)
j=0;["Wow, I don't0know why I0wrote this awful0code for0Programming0Puzzles &0Code Golf.".split(0),["Isn't that...",'PUZZLING?'],[''],['...no? Okay.'],['']][n].map(function(x){
fillText(x,N+40,(j++)*9+y)})}
f(0,0,p/2,400);f(0,100,p/2,400)
}
</script>
```

XKCD-style! (The hand-drawn effect is a bit subtle; I might make it more pronounced later.)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Whew, that was fun! I don't have any more time though, since I have to go, so edits coming some time in the future.

Comment: *If* I understood the size requirements correctly, your comic isn't tall enough.

Comment: @Dennis Ah, good point. I'm on mobile right now so I can't fix it, but I guess I could make it a bit taller tomorrow.