# A challenge about colours

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, graphical-output

[image: the image required for the challenge]

Above, you can see an image full of different colours.

[Click here for a hex-dump.](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/55a291ecd1154618d3fbab36b330d241)

One possible way to generate this image is by using a linear gradient rotated 90 degrees, however, this may not be the only way.

Your task is to create a self-contained program that takes no input, and outputs an image with the same RGBA pixels as the above image, and in the exact same location, with the output image being in a file format that was created before this challenge, with the dimensions of the image being 4096x4096px, same as the original.

The shortest such program, scored in bytes, is the winner.

Cheating and standard loopholes are not allowed.

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22144/images-with-all-colors)

Comment: Earlier versions of this challenge in the sandbox weren't [tag:code-golf], but this version is. I'll go fix the tags for the OP.

Comment: What should the dimensions of the image be?

Comment: @Kritixi Lithos 4096x4096px.

Comment: I assumed them to be 255x255px and have already posted my answer

Comment: @Kritixi Lithos Sorry for not making it clear then, you'll have to modify your answer.

Comment: No alpha channel is present in the posted image. There is just a change in colors, slowly going to all white

Comment: I have already checked. Using 'save image' in the browser, the saved png file has no alpha channel. Probably the PPCG site modified your original image. But in fact there is no image to compare with (and I will not parse the hex dump to get the image back)

Comment: How is this thing generated, please properly define this better.

Comment: This image file: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5d/Hue_alpha_2.svg/4096px-Hue_alpha_2.svg.png has no alpha channel according to my tools

Comment: For instance: http://exif.regex.info/exif.cgi gives `Color Type RGB`. When an alpha channel is present, it gives `Color Type RGB with Alpha`

Comment: Voting to close because I think it should be stated how the pixels are arranged, rather than leaving that as an exercise to the solver. Describe the image.

Comment: @TheBitByte Anyone could brute force it, but it's recognizing the pattern that's hard. Note that some people saw the pattern on their own, but you should put the info in the question anyway.

Comment: @TheBitByte It's not saying how to code it, it's specifying the pattern. Look at ANY other graphical output challenge, like the flag ones. The don't just give an image, they specify the dimensions and widths and how the image is generated. Simply saying "output this image. The end." isn't enough.

Comment: If you don't know how it's specified or created, you probably shouldn't make a challenge on it. The HTML answer seems to see it as a linear gradient rotated 90deg.

Answer (score 3):

## Processing, <s>197</s> 195 bytes

```processing
void setup(){size(255,255);int r=255,a=r,g=0,b=0,i,j,k;background(a);for(i=0;i<a;k=i<43?g+=6:i<85?r-=6:i<a/2?b+=6:i<170?g-=6:i<213?r+=6:a>1?b-=6:0,i++)for(j=0;j<a;point(i,j++))stroke(r,g,b,a-j);}
```

This outputs the image in a 255x255 sized window

#### Explained

```processing
void setup(){            //this is required
  size(255,255);         //size of sketch
  int r=255,a=r,g=0,b=0,i,j,k; //declaring our vars
  background(a);         //set the background colour as white
  //for-loop for the x-coordinates, it also increments/decrements rgb values
  //  based on the x-coordinate
  for(i=0;i<a;k=i<43?g+=6:i<85?r-=6:i<a/2?b+=6:i<170?g-=6:i<213?r+=6:a>1?b-=6:0,i++)
    //for-loop for the y-coordinate (alpha)
    for(j=0;j<a;point(i,j++))   //2) then draw the point at the location
      stroke(r,g,b,a-j);        //1) set the colour of point
}
```

[image]

#### Edits

- Used `int` instead of `float`
- THIS SOLUTION IS INVALID DUE TO NEW RULES BEING ADDED. I WILL UPDATE ANSWER SOON

Comment: Where is update?

Answer (score 2):

## Python, <s>407</s> <s>404</s> 381

I just golfed the svg

```
d='<svg HBdefsTg"BS G"N:redM0YyellowM0.17Y#00ff00M0.33YcyanM0.5YblueM0.67Y#ff00ffM0.83YredM1"/B/LTw" x1Ex2Ey1Ey2="1"BS G"N:white;F:0" O"0YwhiteM1"/B/LB/defsUgVUwVB/svg>'
for R in zip("VTBUEYMNFGOHSLX",')" xEyEH/|BL id="|><|><rect fill="url(#|="0" |"/><S G"N:|;F:1" O"|S-color|S-opacity|style=|offset=|widthXheightX|stop|linearGradient|="4096" '.split('|')):d=d.replace(*R)
print d
```

A raster image can be generated using imagemagick :

```
~$ python snippet.py |convert svg:- hue.png
~$ file hue.png 
hue.png: PNG image data, 4096 x 4096, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
```

Comment: @TheBitByte the generated SVG starts with, `<svg width="4096" height="4096" >` so yes

Answer (score 1):

### HTML/CSS, 166 bytes

```css
p{width:4096px;height:4096px;background:linear-gradient(0deg,#FFF,#FFF0),linear-gradient(90deg,red,#FF0 18.513%,lime 34.256%,aqua 50%,blue 65.43%,#F0F 81.199%,red)
```

```html
<p>
```

Requires a browser that supports #RGBA colours, such as Firefox 49, Chrome 52 or Safari 9.1. I've taken the stops from the original SVG and rounded them to 5sf as that shouldn't make any difference on a 4096 pixel image, but if it does, they could be restored at a small cost. On the other hand, if rounding to either 4sf or whole pixels is OK, then that saves me a further 4 bytes.

Comment: @TheBitByte Sorry I didn't actually try it on Chrome or Safari, I just looked up the compatibility info which suggested that Chrome 52 should work.

Answer (score 1):

## R, <s>95</s> <s>91</s> 88 bytes

```
frame();n=4096;for(i in 1:n){l=matrix(NA,n,n);l[,i]=1:n;image(l,a=T,c=rainbow(n,s=i/n))}
```

When creating plots in while running an R script, by default they are saved to file, either as PNG or PDF. My PC struggles creating the 4096x4096 pixel plot taking up gigs of RAM, but if I change `n` to `256` it matches the correct output.

There are probably some bytes to be saved by making the arguments of `image` shorter, but I'll look at that when I get the supposed output.

[image]