# Smallest image containing one of every RGB color

Tags: code-challenge, image-processing

I'm not sure if this kind of golf is allowed, but here it is.

Your objective is to create an image containing one pixel of every possible RGB color. The image with the smallest file size wins.

Rules:

- The image must be a PNG.
- The image must contain *exactly* one of every possible RGB color.
- Acceptable image dimensions are:

```
1x16777216
2x8388608
4x4194304
8x2097152
16x1048576
32x524288
64x262144
128x131072
256x65536
512x32768
1024x16384
2048x8192
4096x4096
8192x2048
16384x1024
32768x512
65536x256
131072x128
262144x64
524288x32
1048576x16
2097152x8
4194304x4
8388608x2
16777216x1
```

Example Image
[image: Example image]

Comment: What is the scoring criteria? Is it in bytes?

Comment: The image must be a PNG. Can you link to the definition of PNG required? Because different file viewers might support slightly different formats.

Comment: I'm assuming you talk about 24bit colors, but you should specify that in the image

Comment: Why PNG instead of [the defaults](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9093/43319)?

Comment: @Adám Optimizing for different image formats would basically be multiple challenges in one. (note: I'm not OP)

Comment: I think this has [already been done](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22144/images-with-all-colors), albeit as a popularity contest.

Comment: I agree with Adam here, allowing answers to use the easiest image format allows for people to focus on the main task, rather than wasting bytes converting to PNG

Comment: "The image with the smallest file size wins." this suggests that the size of the output is the score, not the size of the program. is this correct? If so, please add the [code-challenge] tag to your question

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I think the sentence "the image with the smallest file size wins" in a challenge named "Smallest image containing one of every RGB color" *very strongly* suggests that the image with the smallest file size wins. (note: I'm not OP)

Comment: @thedefault. I agree that makes the most sense, but currently, the challenge is fairly unclear about a few things, and I’d like the OP to clarify, by editing in the relevant tags, and confirming what I think so that I (or someone else) could edit and make it clearer

Comment: Also, as no one has said it yet, welcome to the site! In the future, we recommend using the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) to get feedback on challenge ideas before posting to main

Comment: Why is this being close voted?

Comment: Is the challenge to create a program that creates such an image, or just to create an image that is the smallest? i.e., optimise the PNG's compression?

Comment: On researching an expert answerer for this question, some sad news was discovered:  [RIP Glenn Randers-Perhson](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20630/rip-glenn-randers-pehrson)

Comment: The challenge to me seems pretty clearly specified - craft a PNG with one of every color with the smallest file size by any means necessary (by hand, by code, etc.)

Comment: This challenge seems clear to me.  Could the users who voted to close say what they find unclear?  The closest I see is @cairdcoinheringaahing saying that multiple things are unclear but not what they are.

Comment: I think this should include either a fixed PNG reader for which solutions must work or the relevant parts of the PNG specification. Without them there are questions as in [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/217544/31625) as to what is allowed.

Answer (score 7):

## <s>49683</s> <s>49280</s> 49131 bytes

[image]

Generated by this Python code. I designed the PNG scanlines by hand to be encoded using repetitions of short sequences that compress well. I’ve now written enough of a custom DEFLATE encoder to let me decide where to split the compressed blocks (saving 149 bytes compared to zlib).

```python
import itertools
import struct
import zlib


def lsb(b, n):
    assert 0 <= n < 1 << b
    return f"{n:0{b}b}"[::-1] if b else ""


def huffman(lengths, letter):
    code = sum(
        1 << lengths[letter] - length
        for other_letter, length in lengths.items()
        if (length, other_letter) < (lengths[letter], letter)
    )
    return f"{code:0{lengths[letter]}b}"


def literal(letter):
    assert 0 <= letter < 256
    return huffman(literals, letter)


def end():
    return huffman(literals, 256)


def match(length, distance):
    assert 3 <= length <= 258
    assert 1 <= distance <= 32768

    if length == 258:
        bits = huffman(literals, 285)
    else:
        i = max(0, (length - 3).bit_length() - 3)
        bits = huffman(literals, 4 * i + 257 + (length - 3 >> i)) + lsb(
            i, length - 3 & ~(~0 << i)
        )

    j = max(0, (distance - 1).bit_length() - 2)
    bits += huffman(distances, 2 * j + (distance - 1 >> j)) + lsb(
        j, distance - 1 & ~(~0 << j)
    )

    return bits


code_length_order = [16, 17, 18, 0, 8, 7, 9, 6, 10, 5, 11, 4, 12, 3, 13, 2, 14, 1, 15]


def encode_lengths():
    hlit = max(literals) + 1 - 257
    hdist = max(distances) + 1 - 1
    hclen = max(map(code_length_order.index, code_lengths)) + 1 - 4
    bits = lsb(5, hlit) + lsb(5, hdist) + lsb(4, hclen)
    for i in code_length_order[: hclen + 4]:
        bits += lsb(3, code_lengths.get(i, 0))
    for length, group in itertools.groupby(
        [literals.get(i, 0) for i in range(hlit + 257)]
        + [distances.get(i, 0) for i in range(hdist + 1)],
        lambda length: length,
    ):
        n = len(list(group))
        while length == 0 and 18 in code_lengths and n >= 11:
            bits += huffman(code_lengths, 18) + lsb(7, min(n - 11, 127))
            n -= min(n - 11, 127) + 11
        while length == 0 and 17 in code_lengths and n >= 3:
            bits += huffman(code_lengths, 17) + lsb(3, min(n - 3, 7))
            n -= min(n - 3, 7) + 3
        # not implemented: 16 (copy previous code)
        bits += huffman(code_lengths, length) * n
    return bits


png_header = struct.pack(
    "!IIBBBBB",
    2 ** 16,  # width
    2 ** 8,  # height
    8,  # bit depth
    2,  # color type
    0,  # compression method
    0,  # filter method
    0,  # interlace method
)

zlib_header = struct.pack(
    "!BB",
    8 | 7 << 4,  # compression method, compression info
    26 | 0 << 5 | 3 << 6,  # check bits, preset dictionary, compression level
)

literals = {1: 2, 2: 4, 256: 4, 268: 4, 284: 4, 285: 1}
distances = {2: 1, 18: 1}
code_lengths = {0: 3, 1: 2, 2: 3, 4: 2, 18: 2}
bits = "0"  # start non-final block
bits += lsb(2, 2)  # compressed with dynamic Huffman codes
bits += encode_lengths()
bits += literal(1) + literal(1) + literal(1) + literal(2) + literal(1) + literal(2)
bits += 2 * match(258, 3)
bits += match(248, 3)
bits += 5 * (
    match(258, 768) + match(258, 3) + 42 * (match(258, 768) + 2 * match(258, 3))
)
bits += match(258, 768) + match(258, 3) + 39 * (match(258, 768) + 2 * match(258, 3))
bits += match(17, 3)
bits += end()

literals = {1: 3, 256: 3, 264: 3, 279: 3, 285: 1}
distances = {0: 1, 2: 1}
code_lengths = {0: 3, 1: 2, 3: 2, 17: 3, 18: 2}
bits += "1"  # start final block
bits += lsb(2, 2)  # compressed with dynamic Huffman codes
bits += encode_lengths()
bits += 96780 * match(258, 1)
bits += match(105, 1)
bits += literal(1) + literal(1)
bits += 762 * match(258, 3)
bits += match(10, 3)
bits += 96780 * match(258, 1)
bits += match(102, 1)
bits += end()

bits += -len(bits) % 8 * "0"
compressed = int(bits[::-1], 2).to_bytes((len(bits) + 7) // 8, "little")

decompressed = zlib.decompress(compressed, wbits=-15)
assert decompressed == bytes(
    [1, *(2 ** 8) * [1, 1, 2, *(2 ** 8 - 1) * [1, 2, 2]]]
    + (2 ** 7 - 1) * [2, *2 ** 16 * [2, 2, 2]]
    + [2, *2 ** 16 * [2, 1, 1]]
    + (2 ** 7 - 1) * [2, *2 ** 16 * [2, 2, 2]]
)

zlib_checksum = struct.pack("!I", zlib.adler32(decompressed))
png_data = zlib_header + compressed + zlib_checksum

png = b"\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n"
for type, data in [(b"IHDR", png_header), (b"IDAT", png_data), (b"IEND", b"")]:
    crc = 0xFFFFFFFF
    for byte in type + data:
        crc ^= byte
        for bit in range(8):
            crc = 0xEDB88320 * (crc & 1) ^ crc >> 1
    crc ^= 0xFFFFFFFF
    png += struct.pack("!I4s", len(data), type) + data + struct.pack("!I", crc)

print(len(png))
with open("rgb.png", "wb") as f:
    f.write(png)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vVhZb9tGEH7nr9iyaLBr0Ywo6rJgBWjgtDFQBEHRN1kxSHEl0SGXBEnFVlznr6cze/CQfCQvNRKTOzvHN8fODp3vq20m/O/f4zTPiorEFS@qLEtKSxPKqtitKrP6msShZVkRX5OkDGnoEMFmFoGfoCxBkvTJ@ZwIck48cn5OQrlV8GpXCLK278Wsfx8@hA/2YjY79ZYkXpOQ8KTkxLa12u1uvU4DQRMuNtW2dEjCK8CkrayyiJM5KXcplWv8kZY0@0JxL8mpptRc66wgWbXlxbVicTQDiYURdsH5tKSslgF4GofTkWXgHz2wWAOV0uzAccQNvh/IYCRMNDHwQUI73rZjqjbA8GA0biuv46UUNAHTirmIqFb3pASoNOxpUK22tdNRXFaBWPEuHl/hkdGDt8Fo2t71kGYE8d0fTMZTy9IB1XJzKTerQx3GVQmJfQTbdKSCiWXS8MfAnAZ3tO@YTEDKfeaCnmu1pkxSXrYwJCegrgd4JvC7pY28eUNixoCItV4rkubr8kG@V@Qb/dbHMowbe0y5fNMCWkfllHhHUAdKVMLsNTiNDIYCgN4gxLYeBHlzDPKmSZ7kaiDemApt1wRahQrAMtWYrrMignqbk4U3dog3gf9Th4AX8BsWZw5BMqxH8PAgivAYOMSHB/yHNw8p8G@0rCuxpb40RbmFROgQmZSgMx5GZDRRLOiJ5qnDYZg8xbICtZolDXJ65Igbi4jfOaQNgRkdQ6tVIBhG8AlxmajiEg2bNXgmDapIYmeJsY0cGV3MNLAeGS4Par2nLPldSO6GVxSKq88a3eYwbopsl6Oduke7khTum7QvTAwbRQ2@IhAbTmXAZbWzZS3XI4s6ss@IykRAzNjSqUWTIA2jQKOcGbSqxhqfMTmwBTkuKyphs@ao3G7jhLc6Q58EIoJ6OwhqKcmCvJlDxc065/Hw1LSlsHJN5qBy01hQgYWDxTmYtGAonKfzIxZ02XsJ7eRptP5PgZ0YsH4DFl6fRSr3QcyvWX4lIoPrPM0TnnJR8WhGvDEBW/me5AX/Eme7UsJl1o/hUi8MepB4pHPkYnO95YFqGWpmcPNg9VmVpv3L5eVb/LFVYUAnOyHYVwDmbRzpa1pSp5K45fFmW0mqIoAZEvHccEraKkugPqt9ziWxr4kpuFeWcSZIymG4iVqb6zjBS/SIHkOAiiSAXqm3oDviqPOsS7U3U/IvmWBrHT6BwOnQYrHOlBdjEJQ9eQQvPr6okKy2fPVZRtbBXJUcfI9XFQgHxb6rLOFfeIJwzcEHrPfeDCM0mCEguNvVczxVz@lQP0dQEQ9WfexREESw5Kdyp1PLsNmfye5udMP7UL4j@@DB0u3T7tvoAiiFWUBk4nQdiyAhYZKtPlvtzodaWDtePIJagCMV7UWQxivyXpWhLNKyFj28RRqdeoLy5PF5cTF4ZqfWiTeumohgWHFwmjA7mjrsUkfAr8qjJQXTD6rv6MEbAZXTY74jm8w6MvuMWv/sh9V2leIV33JFzo1HZeXrgsLneKiekzP1fKyg@rKgBi/Wk68qaaJIrYICJLbXqqj/q5rOxpNpvxsy7yhi/VGH@kTR1fuT8Uv1hPOU/7MgBh2qzptZnuKliwtGfoNGdYLn02rFaI69TzKoTzIMo1tl1@G@4iWljXQPL5jXr7Ed2@BblXCb4VzX0YU9021otNl0yC3qmZ96MM7rL4Wu8Jwom/L4LKBqTqi6EPDKwbUnx0pDlTO03sHkL5dqmoHxWDJMagYU0heOXip@zf7IPhr7eXXmzpDdG75QD24NuANtR0UoiBJe@APaDgCcR7xDo6AKdCDN5dNr13SPdGzIixf4Q/vqbnr28cOfV8WVuLrzgithW2t9O8KnAGqF8WRBQ/vy/cXfAKS5sBl8mQD54vd/NBm5NfHdhwsghrbN9Py6KlZgrn/3h/6pp1RMHppAg4ASdTRTD0p9UgnufJDjrV5Pl1PWHZOMqXcXb6dTf4AHgSLtFSbik9yGbx/Pahk4wIWx6R1lYVjacpqh2k9EzDRkeBznDJRDbvMCTwrKgVrIluwuWQ5ru9iELhCB1b4NbQZfwmStfFm7twU0Aili/sQidinMYMAjcvNnlY@Xf7mXabDhFlDgAX7XJLdroz49ktGFKEIfwNNjQ/ZtK4/vuOzWIneDogj2VPLVUmrfLbdBzhf9JcS0Q/GW8sscy3swlANsZ3sgt31oIDtRaStfeZGVVItAqWE450CHaPlwlSrWBdV6ghL3ab2PQ08NdbFYqA9MbwzHmTEX/84T3MXlHJrSOgmqCiLBlphTT@eDGihz/KQOkoQy9v0/)

(Note: many PNG readers accept an image missing the `IEND` chunk, but it is required by the [PNG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/) so I have included it.)

Answer (score 2):

## 256x65536, 49909 bytes

[image]

<sup>In my experience Google Chrome is the best tool to view this image.</sup>

The red channel starts at 255 in the first row and decreases by 1 each row.
The green channel slowly decreases from 255 to 0 in every row and the blue channel repeatly decreases from 255 to 0.

Generated by the following code in [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) with [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/) and [imageio](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html):

```python
import os

import imageio
import numpy as np

FILENAME = 'out.png'
DTYPE = np.uint8

values = np.arange(255, -1, -1, dtype=DTYPE)
image = np.empty((256, 256**2, 3), dtype=DTYPE)

image[..., 0] = values[:, np.newaxis]  # r
image[..., 1] = np.repeat(values, 256) # g
image[..., 2] = np.tile(values, 256)   # b

# Verify that all colors are present (slow)
# assert len(np.unique(image.reshape(256**3, 3), axis=0)) == 256 ** 3

imageio.imwrite(FILENAME, image)
os.system('wc ' + FILENAME)
```

I tried to reduce the file size with [zopflipng](https://github.com/google/zopfli/blob/master/README.zopflipng), but even after 50 minutes of running it provided no improvement.